# upload images/videos to a php server in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I was using android studio for a few months but when I moved to Codename one everything seemed so different.

I want to make an app to upload image, video and audio to a xammp server in codename one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PHP or XAMMP but the standard way to upload files in HTTP is multipart upload and that's how HTML FORM works. Codename One has builting support for that in the `MultipartRequest` class. You can just add the file to that and submit it to the `NetworkManager`.